# Remove blanks from DAX average total

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table called `Conditions` which links to a table called `Agreement`, relationship on `AgreementID`.

In `Conditions`, I have two measures already pre-calculated in the model called `Margin Pct-EOP` and `Minimum Pct-EOP` which return a value based on the filter context.

I have created measure in Power BI called `InterestRateFloorBoolean` which returns `true` if those measures don't match.

```
InterestRateFloorBoolean = if('Conditions'[Margin Pct-EOP] <> 'Conditions'[Minimum Pct-EOP],true,false)
```

If that measure returns `true`, then a subsequent measure called `InterestRateFloorAmount` runs the below calculation (a simple floored subtraction).

```
if([InterestRateFloorBoolean] = true,floor([Minimum Pct-EOP] - [Margin Pct-EOP],0.01),BLANK())
```

At a row level, the desired output is returned, `blank()` showing where the Margin/Minimum measures match.  However, the Total runs an average of 2 `AgreementID` entries as ID 3236 does have Margin and Minimum values.  ID 3336 is excluded as it does not have any entries.

I get that `blank()` is not the same as `null` and is essentially being treated like a 0 for the purposes of the Total (average).  How can I construct my `InterestRateFloorAmount` measure so that when the total is averaged it does not include any `blank()` values?

Current output by way of illustration, the Total for `InterestRateFloorAmount` should be 4.00% (the percentage is a format):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to calculation context and how the two measures `[Margin Pct-EOP]` and `[Minimum Pct-EOP]` are calculated.

Because in the context of the the total line the calculation it ignores the context of the previous lines. Hence `InterestRateFloorAmount` compares the two measures in the `IF-statement`:

```
InterestFloorAmount = 
IF(
    [InterestRateFloorBoolean] = true,
    floor([Minimum Pct-EOP] - [Margin Pct-EOP], 0.01),
    BLANK()
)
```

however in the context of Total the two measures evaluate to `4.20%` and `2.20%` (these, I assume, are calculated like `(2.25+6.15)/2` and `(2.25+2.15)/2` respectively). Thus 
`InterestFloorBoolean` evaluates to `TRUE` and therefore  `InterestRateFloorAmount` calculates `4.20%-2.20%` and you end up with `2.00%`.

Comment: Thanks, it got me to where I needed, which was essentially to create `var` based nested measures in my new measures with the correct filter contexts.

Comment: Happy it helped you find a solution. Cheers!